# Classes within classes in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Can you do this in PHP? I've heard conflicting opinions:

Something like:

```
Class bar {
   function a_function () { echo "hi!"; }
}

Class foo {
   public $bar;
   function __construct() {
       $this->bar = new bar();
   }
}
$x = new foo();
$x->bar->a_function();
```

Will this echo "hi!" or not?

Comment: Have you tried it, and did it work or not?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function a_function() on a non-object

Comment: How's that a class within a class? It's an object within a class.

Comment: Conflicting opinions? A member variable can take any value. Maybe someone thought that you mean *defining* classes inside other classes (like private classes in Java)...

Comment: @Felix Kling You mean nested classes in Java.

Comment: Sorry, $bar = new bar(); should be $this->bar = new bar();
My mistake. I've updated the post

Comment: @Jan Kuboschek Okaaay... you know what I mean. cut me some slack

Comment: @Matt just wanted to clarify for my own good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine, and I'm not sure why anyone would tell you that you shouldn't be doing it and/or that it can't be done.

Your example won't work because you're assigning `new Bar()` to a variable and not a property, though.

`$this->bar = new Bar();`

Comment: Thanks, realised that, and have changed the example

Answer (score 3):

> Will this echo "hi!" or not?

***No***

Change this line:

```
$bar = new bar();
```

to:

```
$this->bar = new bar();
```

to output:

```
hi!
```

Comment: Yeah :) sorry, forgot to do that
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The only requirement is that (since you're calling it outside both classes), in

```
$x->bar->a_function();
```

both `bar` is a public property and `a_function` is a public function. `a_function` does not have a `public` modifier, but it's implicit since you specified no access modifier.

edit: (you <del>have</del> had a bug, though, see the other answers)

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I thought, but my code always seems to fail right after I start making these nested classes. anyway... I must be the problem. ;)

Comment: @Matt PHP does not support nested classes. This is called object composition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Comment: yeah i've caused a bit of confusion with my wording. I suppose what I really meant was nested objects. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In a class, you need to prefix all member variables with `$this->`.  So your `foo` class's constructor should be:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->bar = new bar();
}
```

Then it should work quite fine...